# Bootstrap Tab wrong URL of actual Page

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tabs

My Bootstrap Tabs are working fine but the URL is built wrong like below. I checked many Sites and mine is definitly wrong.

If I am at **http://domain.com/blog** it shows me:

```
http://domain.com/#vote
```

instead of

```
http://domain.com/blog/#vote
```

If the Javascript has loading problems it should still go to the Anchor and not to the URL.

My HTML

```
<div class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <a href="#vote" aria-controls="vote" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
        {lang key="Votes" section="global"}
    </a>
</div>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="vote">
    Votes
</div>
```

Javascript

```
// Tabs
$('.nav-tabs a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is all your HTML markup, then you are using an incorrect HTML structure. according to the [documentation for javascript bootstrap tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs).

I have tested the following on my own localhost, and your example as well. With the official version there is no issue, while what you have copied above had a broken styling and it did not properly work.

**Example**

```
<!-- start container for tabs, required -->
<div role="tabpanel">

    <!-- Nav tabs menu, required -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">

        <!-- repeat the row below for extra menu items, 3x used in example -->
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#tab1" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab1 title</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab2" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2 title</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#tab3" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3 title</a></li>

    <!-- close tabs menu -->
    </ul>

    <!-- start tab content panes container. do not forget this, required -->
    <div class="tab-content">

        <!-- repeating content pane. make sure that the id="xxxx" matches the href from the menu item -->
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">tab 1 content</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab2">tab 2 content</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tab3">tab 3 content</div>

    <!-- close tab content panes -->
    </div>

<!-- close container for tabs -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Erik to your reply.. I just put a part of the Code.. Even if I put the full Code of Bootstraps Example the URL is taking just the Base URL and than the Anchro like above :(

Comment: can you try hardcoding the links to 
http://domain.com/blog#tab1, 
http://domain.com/blog#tab2, 
http://domain.com/blog#tab3
- this works on my localhost. you can also try the dynamic version of /blog#tab1, /blog#tab2, /blog#tab3

Comment: Yes that is working. I tried that already but just was wondering why it is not working for me.

Comment: it might have something to do with your .htaccess mod rewrite settings if you are using it. basically # anchors should apply to your current page, which means that your website thinks that your /blog layer is more of a parameter than a page. that is the only thing i can come up with, unfortunately my .htaccess background is not deep enough to help you with that, sorry

Comment: You are right.. It is a parameter and not a page. Removed the index of htaccess but the same problem.. Removed custom javascript too but same result. Makes me crazy

Comment: At least you was right. I had a plugin for SEO URL which destroyed the URL. Thank you very much Erik!!